# Is there an elegant method to find the minimum value of $\frac{\sqrt{x^{4}+x^{2}+2 x+1}+\sqrt{x^{4}-2 x^{3}+5 x^{2}-4 x+1}}{x}$ for positive $x$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima, triangle-inequality

> Find the minimum value of $\frac{\sqrt{x^{4}+x^{2}+2 x+1}+\sqrt{x^{4}-2 x^{3}+5 x^{2}-4 x+1}}{x}$ for $x\gt0$.

In some textbook, the problem is usually tackled by calculus. So I started to investigate the problem using triangle inequality only.  The answer is so interesting and simple that the minimum value of $S(x)$ is $\sqrt{10}$ when $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{6}$.

***My Question:***
How many elegant methods are there to find the minimum point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are going to find the minimum value of}
$$ S(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^{4}+x^{2}+2 x+1}+\sqrt{x^{4}-2 x^{3}+5 x^{2}-4 x+1}}{x}$$
geometrically using Triangle Inequality.

$$\displaystyle \begin{aligned} S(x)&=\sqrt{x^{2}+1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}} +\sqrt{x^{2}-2 x+5-\frac{4}{x}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}} \\&=\sqrt{x^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^{2}} +\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{x}-2\right)^{2}}\end{aligned}$$
$\textrm{which is the sum of distances of any point }P\text{ on a rectangular hyperbola from }(0,-1)$
$\textrm{and }(1,2) \textrm{ as shown below:}$

[image]

Since $S(x) =A P+P B  \geqslant A B =\sqrt{(1-0)^{2}+(2-(-1))^{2}}=\sqrt{10},$
therefore the minimum value of S(x) is $\sqrt{10},\\ $ when and only when A, B and P are collinear$ \quad \textrm{ i.e. }  \dfrac{2-\frac{1}{x}}{1-x}=\dfrac{2-(-1)}{1-0 }
\Leftrightarrow  \dfrac{2 x-1}{1-x}=3 x \Leftrightarrow  3 x^{2}-x-1=0 \Leftrightarrow  x=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{13}}{6}. $

We can now conclude that the minimum value of S(x) is $\sqrt{10}$ when $x=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{13}}{6}.$

Comment: Beautiful (+1). A question for you. To generalize, how much is this methodology dependent on  the exact coefficients of the polynomial that you have under the square root ?

Comment: Good idea!Thank you.